# Does the sentence "I like watching YouTube" sound natural?

Tags: word-usage

I am aware that when you use *watch* with *TV*, it sounds pefectly natural, but I have never heard some say something like

> I like watching YouTube.

Is it at all natural?

Comment: Well, I think it is more natural to say "I like watching videos on YouTube." or "I like watching YouTube videos."

Comment: it is all natural..means no living soul would be confused understanding it!

Comment: That sounds perfectly idiomatic to me.